# Form Box Weird in Chrome

Tags: css, forms, google-chrome, safari

Any reason a form would act like this? It is causing a CSS issue between Safari and Chrome. The form is above the actual box for some reason.

[image]

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out finally - there was a float:right; on the actual input itself that was causing the input to go outside of the form on Chrome and FF - but not Safari. Hope this can help someone else out!